# Android: when Activity receives a broadcast how to detect if sender is the Activity itself?

Tags: broadcastreceiver, ipc, localbroadcastmanager

My Android app uses `LocalBroadcastManager` and `BroadcastReceiver` to communicate between activities.  How do you have an activity detect when it is receiving an `Intent` that originated from itself rather than another `Activity`?  In other words, how do you get the broadcast caller and ignore it if it equals `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of if there's a specific way of doing this, but, I would add a specific `action` to my `Intent` that is being broadcast. It could look like this:

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(MyClass.class.getName());
sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

Then when you receive the broadcast, you'll simply just check for the specific action:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(MyClass.class.getName()) {
        // Ignore the broadcast as it's the caller calling itself...
    } else {
        // Do something with the broadcast...
    }
}
```

There might be other ways to do this (like just putting extras into the `Intent` and then reading it out in the `onReceive` method), but I find this to be a really simple way of getting who the caller is.

Comment: Adding an extra to the intent identifying the class of the sender did the job, thank you.